# Matching elements that are not nested (scrapy)

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm fairly new to Python and trying scrapy for the first time and am stuck at grouping HTML elements that are not nested.

So basically two HTML elements are repeated every time, and belong together. Since UL is not nested within H2 I'm stuck at how to pair them.

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is getting a list of dates and vulnerabilities using the following structured data:

```
March 10, 2020 (Date)
.MFSA 2020-10 (UID) 
..Level high (Severity)
../en-US/security/advisories/mfsa2020-10/ (Url)
..Security Vulnerabilities fixed in Thunderbird 68.6 (Description)
.MFSA 2020-09 (UID) 
..Level high (Severity)
../en-US/security/advisories/mfsa2020-09/ (Url)
..Security Vulnerabilities fixed in Firefox ESR 68.6 (Description)
```

What I've done so far is manually scraping with the shell using:

```
scrapy shell 'https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/advisories/' 

>>>response.css('article.mzp-c-article h2::text').get()
'March 10, 2020'

>>>response.css('article.mzp-c-article a::attr(href)').get()
'/en-US/security/advisories/mfsa2020-10/'

>>>response.css('li.level-item span::attr(class)')[4].get() # first few results are severity index
'level critical'

>>>response.css('li.level-item a::text').get()
' Security Vulnerabilities fixed in Thunderbird 68.6'
```

The problem is that i'm not able to match Uid, Severity, URL and Description with Date this way.

I thought about collecting all data for each ul using 'response.css('article.mzp-c-article ul').getall()[$n]' and using RE to deconstruct the required data, but that feels like a PITA. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll have to use xpath rather than css in this case.

```
response.xpath('//article//h2::following-sibling/ul/li/a/@href').extract()
```

I could probably misspell some html, but overall you should take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp

Comment: Worked like a charm! for anyone interested:
`response.xpath('//h2[1]/following-sibling::ul[1]/li/a/@href').extract()`